# como usar un href en una etiqueta que no sea (a)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy usando una etiqueta **a** con un href que llama un **id** para que haga su función

```
<a href="#openModal">Abrir</a>
```

sucede que no puedo usar una etiqueta **a** en estos momentos porque se me daña todo el trabajo, quiero saber que otra etiqueta puedo usar y que funcione href, ya que he intentado ponerlo en otra etiquetas pero no me funciona.

Comment: a que te refieres con que se te daña? que efecto negativo en tu trabajo genera?

Comment: Ejemplo cuando tengo una etiqueta img,  esa etiqueta que tiene una imagen  al hacer click necesito que abra el modal pero el href no sirve en la etiqueta img.

Comment: Que vas hacer con el href? solo obtener el id?

Comment: si, para que abra el modal

Comment: Ok perfecto entonces te haré un código sin el tag a para que puedas llamar o abrir la modal.

Comment: No veo en qué puede afectar usar una etiqueta `a`, si tienes una imagen puedes envolverla en una etiqueta `a` y listo: `<a href="tu/ruta"><img src="ruta/imagen.png"></a>`

Comment: el atributo `href `puede ser utilizado también con 
`<area>`, `<base> `y `<link>`. Pero estoy de acuerdo con los demás: por favor pon un ejemplo con más código para poder entender de que va.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No es posible usar el atributo en otra etiqueta `html`, podrías en teoría usarla en otro elemento, pero no funcionará y siempre se validará como incorrecto.**

Me temo que la solución a tu problema es contextualmente otra, pero necesitaríamos más información de tu proyecto, específicamente ¿Cómo "daña" el tener este atributo en el enlace? o ¿Cuál es el script de `js` que estás usando para controlar el evento? ¿Cual es la estructura html y css de tu página? porque en teoría no debería afectar el tener más de una etiqueta `<a>` en lógica de llamar un modal.

Ahora, también, lo cierto es que no es necesario usar específicamente el atributo `href` para que funcione el modal, de hecho podrías lograr el mismo evento con otro atributo de tipo data, ejemplo `data-href="#ejemplo"`.

Answer (score 2):

La etiqueta `<a>` no afecta a lo que se ve, con estilos puedes hacer que se vea como un botón, puede "rodear" una imagen sin afectar a esta.... lo que necesites:

```css
a.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4AF;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> Enlace normal</a>
<a class="btn"href="#"> Enlace como botón</a>

<a href="#">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Enlace%20imagen"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como lo comentaste en el comentario valga la redundancia el atributo **href** solo lo usas para abrir una modal, y dices que el tag `<a>` te da problemas entonces hagamos otra solución para que abras la modal sin la etiqueta `<a>` y obtener el id de la modal que quieres abrir:

```js
$(".abrir").on("click", (e) => {

 let id = $(e.target).attr("href");
 let id2 = $(e.target).attr("data-href");
 alert("El id por el atributo href es: "+id+" y el id por el atributo data-href: "+id2);
 
});

const div = document.getElementsByClassName("abrir2")[0];
div.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let id = div.getAttribute("href");
  let id2 = div.getAttribute("data-href");
  alert("href es: "+id+" y el id por el atributo data-href: "+id2);
});
```

```css
.abrir,
.abrir2{
 border:1px solid red;
 border-radius:3px;
 display:inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 transition: all .3s;
}

.abrir:hover,
.abrir2:hover{
 background: black;
 color:white;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abrir" href="#modal" data-href="#modal">Abrir modal Jquery</div>

<div class="abrir2" href="#modal" data-href="#modal">Abrir modal JS puro</div>
```

Si te fijaste te cree dos opciones un con **Jquery** y otra con **Js puro**, usa la que mas te convenga, la idea es obtener el id obtiendo el atributo en este caso **href** del div, aunque href no es un atributo propio del div puedes declararlo y usarlo como un seudoaributo, eso quiere decir que no te afectara en los comportamientos propios del div, si tambien te fijates cree otro atributo llamado **data-href** para que vieras que puedes crear un atributo con un nombre que te convenga, en estos tiempo se esta usando mucho el **data-algo**, puede usar ese para obtener el id de la modal o usa el href como mejor te plazca, una vez obtiene el id puede invocar tu modal y hacerla abrir con un método propio de la modal, ejemplo en bootstrap la abririas asi: `$("#modal").modal("show");`, no se que plugin estas usando pero ya tienes la idea general, obtiene el id y luego invocas el método que haría abrir tu modal. Espero te funcione.

**Ejemplo llamando a un modal con Bootstrap:**

```
$(".abrir").on("click", (e) => {

 let id = $(e.target).attr("href");

 $(id).modal("show");

});
```